# glReadPixels GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT crashes QT application

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I want to use glReadPixels with GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT in my QT application to make sure users can only select visible vertices with their mouse. When I attempt to do so, my application crashes with the following error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF94E60823 (ig75icd64.dll) in
>   qtopenglsphere.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0x00000000000000A8.

A couple of notes:

- using glreadpixels with GL_RED returns correct results
- my integrated GPU is an Intel HD 4600. ig75icd64.dll in the error above seems to be the OpenGL driver for it. "OpenGL extensions viewer" reports this GPU to be 100% compatible with OpenGL 4.3 and earlier.
- at the moment the program is drawing a 3D cube in perspective with depth testing enabled and the cube looks fine.

Main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QTextStream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setSamples(16);
    format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
    format.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL);
    format.setVersion(4, 0);
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

glwidget.cpp - initialiseGL()

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    glClearColor(0,0,0,1);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex,
        "uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;\n"
        "in vec4 vertex;\n"
        "in vec4 color;\n"
        "out vec4 varyingColor;\n"
        "void main(void)\n"
        "{\n"
        "varyingColor = color;\n"
        "gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vertex;\n"
        "}");
    shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment,
        "in vec4 varyingColor;\n"
        "out vec4 fragColor;\n"
        "void main(void)\n"
        "{\n"
        "   gl_FragColor = varyingColor;\n"
        "}");
    shaderProgram.link();

<definition of cube vertices>

}
```

glwidget.cpp - paintGL()

```
void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    mMatrix.setToIdentity();
    vMatrix.setToIdentity();

    QMatrix4x4 cameraTransformation;
    cameraTransformation.rotate(alpha, 0, 1, 0);
    cameraTransformation.rotate(beta, 1, 0, 0);
    QVector3D cameraPosition = cameraTransformation* QVector3D(0, 0, distance);
    QVector3D cameraUpDirection = cameraTransformation * QVector3D(0, 1, 0);
    QVector3D cameratranslate(panx,pany,0);
    cameratranslate = cameraTransformation*cameratranslate;
    cameraPosition += cameratranslate;
    vMatrix.lookAt(cameraPosition, cameratranslate, cameraUpDirection);

    shaderProgram.bind();
    shaderProgram.setUniformValue("mvpMatrix", pMatrix * vMatrix * mMatrix);
    shaderProgram.setAttributeArray("vertex", vertices.constData());
    shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("vertex");
    shaderProgram.setAttributeArray("color", colors.constData());
    shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("color");
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());
    shaderProgram.disableAttributeArray("vertex");
    shaderProgram.disableAttributeArray("color");

    shaderProgram.release();
}
```

glwidget.cpp - findSelectedVertex(QPoint)

```
void GLWidget::findSelectedVertex(QPoint clickpoint)
{
    float mousex = clickpoint.x();
    float mousey = clickpoint.y();
    float renderedPixelDepth;
    glReadPixels(mousex,height()-mousey,1,1,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,GL_FLOAT,&renderedPixelDepth);// EXCEPTION THROWN HERE
    QTextStream(stdout) << "Clicked point value = " << renderedPixelDepth << endl;
}
```

It seems strange to me that I can use glReadPixels with GL_RED but not with GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT. I've tried to make sure I'm using OpenGL4.0 instead of OpenGL ES 2.0 (which doesn't have GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT), but perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

A compliant OpenGL implementation is not allowed to throw an exception because of providing enumaration or values to operations not supported by a driver such as `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` to `glReadPixels`. If unsupported the operation will record an error retrievable by `glGetError` and proceed as if the operation was never called.

You are not clear as to what line is crashing. My guess is that the `glReadPixels` operation fail because of `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT`+`GL_FLOAT` is not supported and the now uninitialized float causes problem in the print operation. If that is from where the exception is thrown at all.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. The glReadPixels line is the problem and causes the exception. I never actually reach the line where I print. Using GL_RED and float returns a value from 0 to 1, the same as expected from GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, so I don't see how that could be an issue either.

Comment: I´ve had my fair share of unreliable debuggers... Is there any optimization turned on that may interfere with the debugger? Have you tried executing the application in a graphics debugger such as gDEBugger or CodeXL and break on error?

As for solving your problem I´m at loss. The code looks fine to me. I´ve been with platforms not supporting some of the glReadPixels enumerations (Mesa) and the result was an OpenGL error and data not written to, just as defined by the standard. Then again which subset is supported is not queryable from OpenGL as a subset is de facto non-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

glReadPixels and GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT do have problems on Intel.
I had the exact same problem with it.
On every other hardware than Intel Graphics there is no problem.

I got rid of the crash by using another buffer format.
GL_BGR

Now it works on all Intel Graphics, tested ~10 different ones.

Answer (score -1):

This line is the point:

```
format.setSamples(16);
```

**Multiple sampling** will change the original pixel, just **delete** this line.